# Why isn't this basic Sass nesting example working?

Tags: css, sass, nested

I'm starting to learn Sass and started to check some nesting examples. This is the first one I tried and it's not working:

```
body {background:#eee;}

.blog .entry {
    p{
        color:#ff0;
    }
}
```

This is my markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.scss">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="blog">
        <div class="entry">
            <h1>My blog post</h1>
            <p class="blue">Text <a>link</a></p>
        </div><!-- .entry -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The background of the body does change to #eee, but the paragraph stays the same (unless I un-nest it to just p{} ).

Comment: can you give me the code from your complied scss file?

Comment: What does the compiled CSS look like? What happens if you remove the "blue" class

Comment: You can't link an SCSS/SASS file like a CSS one. That's not the way SASS works. You have to complie it first...unless you're doing that client side...whch I doubt.

Comment: is this your sass code or compiled code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you cannot link an SCSS file just like CSS, you have to compile it to CSS then link the compiled file.
In order to nest properly in SCSS you can do the following:

```
.blog {
  .entry {
      p{
          color:#ff0;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, blew way past the <link> stuff. To be clear, I WAS linking to the .scss and the browser cannot read Sass (pretty much the first thing they tell you).

Comment: @brunouno its pretty much the first thing I noticed! Please mark this as solved! Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Your markup and Sass work as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/6pa0r48g/

Please check the compiled CSS directly if you are overloading your css rule by another one (i. e. by formatting `.blue`).

Also this would be more readable:

```
body {
    background: #eee;
}

.blog {
    .entry {
        p {
            color: #ff0;
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend to not go any deeper with your nesting in Sass.